# Limit set for IFS has either empty interior or dense interior

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_k:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ be contracting affine maps. By the theory of iterated function systems, there is a unique minimal compact $K\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ such that $K=f_1(K)\cup\cdots\cup f_k(K)$, known as the limit set of the IFS $\{f_1,\ldots,f_k\}$.

**Proposition**: $\overline{\operatorname{int}(K)}$ is either $\emptyset$ or $K$.

I believe I have a proof using only point-set topology. This looks like it would be well-known, but I couldn't find anything in the literature. Does anyone know a source?

Comment: Suggestions on how to improve this question would be appreciated.